# having difficulty installing protocol buffer on ubuntu

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto

I need a specific version of protocol buffer which is  `3.14.0`  on **apt** its not available like this

```
sudo apt install -y protobuf-compiler = 3.14.0
```

and If I follow these steps by binary :

```
$ PB_REL="https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases"
$ curl -LO $PB_REL/download/v3.14.0/protoc-3.14.0-linux-x86_64.zip
```

then

```
unzip protoc-3.14.0-linux-x86_64.zip -d $HOME/.local
```

then

```
$ export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin"
```

from this  [source](https://grpc.io/docs/protoc-installation/)

and it's not getting install when I do `protoc --version`  I am getting  this error

```
bash: /usr/bin/protoc: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Because /usr/bin/protoc doesn't exist. When you unzipped you got folder named protoc-3.14.0.
which is /usr/bin/protoc-3.14.0

try doing this

```
PROTOC_ZIP=protoc-3.14.0-linux-x86_64.zip
curl -OL https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.14.0/$PROTOC_ZIP
sudo unzip -o $PROTOC_ZIP -d /usr/local bin/protoc
```

ref: http://google.github.io/proto-lens/installing-protoc.html

Comment: getting this   now   `bash: /usr/local/bin/protoc: Permission denied`

Comment: Why do we have two arguments to -d in the third step?

Answer (score 1):

Please check out the following steps to Install protoc on Ubundu, Run the commands 1 to 4 on terminal. Then 5 and 6 to finalize the settings.

Get the latest version tag of protoc release and assign it to variable:

1.

```
PROTOC_VERSION=$(curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/latest" | grep -Po '"tag_name": "v\K[0-9.]+')
```

2. 

```
 curl -Lo protoc.zip "https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/latest/download/protoc-${PROTOC_VERSION}-linux-x86_64.zip"
```

3. Run the following command to extract executable file from a ZIP archive:

   sudo unzip -q protoc.zip bin/protoc -d /usr/local
4. Set execute permission:

   sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/protoc

Now protoc command is available for all users as a system-wide command.

5. We can now check protoc version:

   protoc --version
6. Remove unnecessary ZIP archive:

   rm -rf protoc.zip